# How to create a simple survey using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi sorry for my noob question but I'm having trouble creating a simple survey flow with about 3 questions. Each question has multiple choices and the user clicks on an option then click NEXT, and the next question appears. Once the user has answered the last question, he will click on "Claim your prize" to be taken to another site. How could I do that with Jquery? I have searched everywhere but can't find the solution.

like this page: http://freebies.clubelli.com/

but the questions have multiple choices with no right or wrong answer

Comment: May be you want to start with [jQuery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513667/creating-a-survey-using-jquery-any-examples

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jq-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script>
$(function(){
    var jQuiz = {
        answers: { q1: 'd', q2: 'd', q3: 'a', q4: 'c', q5: 'a' },
        questionLength: 5,
        checkAnswers: function() {
            var arr = this.answers;
            var ans = this.userAnswers;
            var resultArr = []
            for (var p in ans) {
                var x = parseInt(p) + 1;
                var key = 'q' + x;
                var flag = false;
                if (ans[p] == 'q' + x + '-' + arr[key]) {
                    flag = true;
                }
                else {
                    flag = false;
                }
                resultArr.push(flag);
            }
            return resultArr;
        },
        init: function(){
            $('.btnNext').click(function(){
                if ($('input[type=radio]:checked:visible').length == 0) {

                    return false;
                }
                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
                });
                var el = $('#progress');
                el.width(el.width() + 120 + 'px');
            });
            $('.btnPrev').click(function(){
                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).prev().fadeIn(500)
                });
                var el = $('#progress');
                el.width(el.width() - 120 + 'px');
            })
            $('.btnShowResult').click(function(){
                var arr = $('input[type=radio]:checked');
                var ans = jQuiz.userAnswers = [];
                for (var i = 0, ii = arr.length; i < ii; i++) {
                    ans.push(arr[i].getAttribute('id'))
                }
            })
            $('.btnShowResult').click(function(){
                $('#progress').width(300);
                $('#progressKeeper').hide();
                var results = jQuiz.checkAnswers();
                var resultSet = '';
                var trueCount = 0;
                for (var i = 0, ii = results.length; i < ii; i++){
                    if (results[i] == true) trueCount++;
                    resultSet += '<div> Question ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + results[i] + '</div>'
                }
                resultSet += '<div class="totalScore">Your total score is ' + trueCount * 20 + ' / 100</div>'
                $('#resultKeeper').html(resultSet).show();
            })

        $('.btnShowResult').click(function(){
                $('#answer').width(300);
                $('#answerKeeper').hide();
                var results = jQuiz.checkAnswers();
                var resultSet = '';
                var trueCount = 0;
                for (var i = 0, ii = results.length; i < ii; i++){
                    if (results[i] == true) trueCount++;
                    resultSet += '<div> Question ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + results[i] + '</div>'
                }
                resultSet += '<div class="totalScore">Your total score is ' + trueCount * 20 + ' / 100</div>'
                $('#answerKeeper').html(resultSet).show();
            })
        }
    };
    jQuiz.init();
})

</script>
```